# Trying to dynamically change Button's text causes system.runtime.interopservices.comexception in .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, maui

Well, the situation is that I'm going to use Timer in a simple quiz MAUI app. And I wanted to show timer changing numbers as a Button text. It works well on WinForms app, but on MAUI it caused `system.runtime.interopservices.comexception 0x8001010e rpc_e_wrong_thread`  exception.

So, is it possible to do that and if yes how to?
Here is a method where the exception occures:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timePerQuestion--;

        //next line causes an exception
        sendAnswerButton.Text = $"Send ({timePerQuestion} {secondsSpelling(timePerQuestion)})";
        if (timePerQuestion == 0)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            SendAnswer_Clicked(sender, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

I'm new to .NET MAUI and have no clue how to deal with multithreading in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update the UI, you need to run the code on the main thread. So you can try to use the `BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, such as:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>
   {
     sendAnswerButton.Text = $"Send ({timePerQuestion} {secondsSpelling(timePerQuestion)})";
   });
```

For more information about the Main thread, you can refert to [Which is better MainThread.Being/InvokeVS Dispatcher.Dispatch](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/7518).